# Поиск исключительно по адресу, городу, дому, но без организаций! Отключение информации об пунтке выдачи

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

**Привет**, делаю карту и не могу сдвинуться с места из-за этой проблемы. **Суть** в том, чтобы **в поисковике нельзя было искать организации**, чтобы предлагало исключительно адреса городов, домов, улиц и т.п. Как можно это сделать? Также встал вопрос, **как убрать информацию, которую выводит по нажатию на метку**(приложен скрин). Можно ли её закастомить, чтобы была кнопка "выбрать", например?? Может есть **какие-нибудь опции**, которые я не увидел? Заранее спасибо!!!

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.796129, 49.106408],
        zoom: 12,
        controls: ["geolocationControl"],
    }, {
        yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true
    }
);
var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    options: {
        provider: "yandex#search",
        noPopup: true,
        noSuggestPanel: true,
        noPlacemark: true,
    },
});
```

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы контрол поиска искал только топонимы, следует указывать ему [провайдер](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl#param-parameters.options.provider) как **yandex#map**, не **yandex#search**.

Кастомизировать **POI** нельзя. Только отключить их интерактивность через [yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/Map#param-options.yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity), что уже реализовано в вашем примере.